# How to use vectorization instead of for loop to improve efficiency in python?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, loops

I've been having trouble with the run time of my code as it is taking too long.
I imagine this is because I am using for loops which is what I'm used to in MATLAB where *for loops* seems to be quicker than in Python.
I've been trying for a while to use *NumPy* vectorization methods to do this instead as I have read this is better in terms of efficiency. However, I seem to be having issues implementing this. I would very much appreciate any guidance on how to do this.

The loop I am trying to do this on is

```
        for i in range(100000):
         theta = theta_rec[:][i]
         A = np.zeros((50,50))

          for k in range(50):
            for j in range(50):
              A[k,j] = math.sin(theta[j] - theta[k])

          B = -1 * np.array(sum(A))
          d_theta = 0.001*(5 + B)
          theta[(i+1),:] = theta_rec[i,:] + d_theta

          for m in range(50):
            D[(i+1),m] = theta_rec[(i+1),m]%(2.0*math.pi)
```

where theta_rec is a 100001x50 array. As you can see this deeply nested for loop isn't good for runtime and is acting as a bottleneck in my code.

In other words, I want to replace this for loop with some sort of NumPy vectorization function as this will improve run time performance. In particular, I think the inner 2 loops would benefit from this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Could you maybe describe in plain words (or in math notation) what you're trying to do?

Comment: @orlp, Thanks for the reply. I added some further explanation in the post. I am mainly wanting to replace the for loops with vector operations as this is more efficient in Python.

Comment: I mean, what is the calculation supposed to do. Right now it's very unclear and it appears to be doing nothing as it overwrites `theta` each iteration, so nothing gets saved. You also say `theta_rec` is 50 by 50 but then index it by `i` which goes up to 100k.

Comment: For starters, **don't do ths: `A = np.array([[0.0 for j in range(50)] for i in range(50)])`** Tht should just be `np.zeros((50, 50))`

Comment: @orlp, I see, sorry my mistake I should have made that more clear, theta_rec is 100001x50. Essentially, every step i, I extract the values of theta and store it in a 100001x50 array.

Comment: You still don't use any of your computations... You never update `theta_rec` and `D[(i+1),m] = theta_rec[(i+1),m]%(2.0*math.pi)` stores from `theta_rec`. Should that be `theta` instead, in the last line?

Comment: @orlp ```theta[(i+1),:]``` is updated every ith iteration, so the ```theta``` term thus changes every iteration. Therefore the computation is used for the next iteration. As for the D term array, this is extracted and then used later in the code.